# WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY vs WM_NOTIFY

Tags: winapi, window-messages, windows-controls

The documentation for [WM_NOTIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is easy enough to find, however I'm finding a fair amount of sample code and articles that refer to `WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY`, for which I can't find any documentation.

What is `WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY`, where can I find the documentation for it and how is this message different from `WM_NOTIFY`?

Example references:

- [Flickering in listview with ownerdraw and virtualmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938896/flickering-in-listview-with-ownerdraw-and-virtualmode)
- [ListViewSubItem.Bounds almost works](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY` is referred to as having value of `0x204E`, that is `0x2000` + `WM_NOTIFY`. Typical use of message reflection is to send back notification to its origin so that supposedly subclassed control could handle notification itself.

Hence the knowledge you are possibly missing and looking documentation for is that the control sends `WM_NOTIFY` to its parent in a regular way. And the parent does `SendMessage` with the same message parameters back to the control using message number `0x2000` + original `Msg`. The meaning of the parameters `wParam`, `lParam` is supposed to be the same of original message (`WM_NOTIFY` in your case).

The constant `0x2000` might possibly vary from framework to framework or be otherwise private agreement between controls and hosting windows.

MFC and ActiveX controls, for instance, reflect `WM_NOTIFY` messages making them `OCM_NOTIFY` messages, where (olectl.h):

```
#define OCM_NOTIFY            (OCM__BASE + WM_NOTIFY)
#define OCM__BASE           (WM_USER+0x1c00)
```

and finally (winuser.h):

```
#define WM_USER                         0x0400
```

That is, the `OCM_NOTIFY` is `0x204E`, just as your `WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY`. The MSDN docs on those from here: [Reflected Window Message IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h15f4z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).