# How to catch LVN_BEGINSCROLL with WM_NOTIFY for a subclass of ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1182232/258462) it is suggested to use this to get the scroll event produced with the mouse wheel. I read [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-notify) but still do not know how to use this in C#. I have code mostly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1852053/258462).

My code is this:

```
internal class EnhancedListView : ListView
{
    internal event ScrollEventHandler ScrollEnded,
        ScrollStarted;

    const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E;

    internal EnhancedListView()
    {
        Scroll += EnhancedListView_Scroll;
    }

    ScrollEventType mLastScroll = ScrollEventType.EndScroll;
    private void EnhancedListView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
        {
            ScrollEnded?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        else if (mLastScroll == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
        {
            ScrollStarted?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        mLastScroll = e.Type;
    }

    internal event ScrollEventHandler Scroll;

    protected virtual void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Scroll?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == 0x115)
        {
            // WM_VSCROLL
            OnScroll(
                new ScrollEventArgs(
                    (ScrollEventType)(m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff),
                    0
                )
            );
        }
        else if (m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY)
        {
            // What should I put here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't listening for the MouseWheel event, if that is what the question is.

Comment: `WM_NOTIFY` is sent by the control to its Parent. You'll see that coupled with `WM_SETCURSOR` all the time. Look at the answer you linked and move one answer up. You'll have to handle directly all the cursor (Key presses) movements.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across your question whilst trying to solve the same problem. I've synthesized the following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618365) (about handling `WM_NOTIFY` messages) and [the Wine source code](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/commctrl.h) (which gives an integer value for `LVN_BEGINSCROLL`):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct NMHDR
{
    public IntPtr hwndFrom;
    public IntPtr idFrom;
    public int code;
}

const int LVN_FIRST = -100;
const int LVN_BEGINSCROLL = LVN_FIRST - 80;

const int WM_REFLECT = 0x2000;

...

else if(m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY + WM_REFLECT)
{
    var notify = (NMHDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NMHDR));
    if(notify.code == LVN_BEGINSCROLL)
    {
        OnScroll(new ScrollEventArgs((ScrollEventType)(m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff), 0));
    }
}
```